# Rails + AngularJS - page refreshing doesn't work on localhost

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku

I'm working on Rails 4.2 + AngularJS 1.5 project and faced pretty weird problem. When I'm trying to refresh (F5) my project's main web-page it's a big chance (let's say 9/10) that refresh will not be performed properly. In that case all I see is my `application.html.haml` layout content (e.g. just "ToDoDoo" header):

```
!!!
%html{"ng-app" => "tododoo"}
  %head
    %title Tododoo
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    .row#header-row
      .col-md-8.col-md-offset-2
        %h1#main-header
          ToDoDoo

    = yield
```

And with chances 1/10 it will refresh page properly and in that case I see  my layout content as well as the angular template which should actually be rendered on the `/` route. It lays in `app/assets/javascripts/templates/projects/index.html.haml`. For now I don't think its code really matters for my problem but I'll add it if you'd like to see it.

**UPDATE:** If refresh was performed well I have in my server console:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:15:35 +0200
Processing by MainController#index as HTML
  Rendered main/index.html.haml within layouts/application (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 54ms (Views: 53.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bg.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:15:35 +0200


Started GET "/projects?format=json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:15:35 +0200
Processing by ProjectsController#index as JSON
  Project Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 2]]
  Task Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 4]]
  Comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 26]]
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.2ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_task.json.jbuilder (8.6ms)
  Comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 27]]
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.2ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.2ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.3ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.5ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.3ms)
  Rendered shared/_task.json.jbuilder (14.7ms)
  Comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 28]]
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_task.json.jbuilder (4.4ms)
  Rendered projects/_project.json.jbuilder (33.1ms)
  Task Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 5]]
  Comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 29]]
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_task.json.jbuilder (7.0ms)
  Rendered projects/_project.json.jbuilder (12.7ms)
  Task Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 6]]
  Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 30]]
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_task.json.jbuilder (8.0ms)
  Comment Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 31]]
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.2ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_task.json.jbuilder (23.2ms)
  Comment Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 32]]
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.5ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.2ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.2ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_task.json.jbuilder (20.0ms)
  Comment Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 33]]
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.2ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_task.json.jbuilder (8.3ms)
  Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 34]]
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_task.json.jbuilder (2.6ms)
  Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 35]]
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/_comment.json.jbuilder (0.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_task.json.jbuilder (6.6ms)
  Rendered projects/_project.json.jbuilder (75.1ms)
  Rendered projects/index.json.jbuilder (135.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 139ms (Views: 128.5ms | ActiveRecord: 9.8ms)


Started GET "/tasks?format=json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:15:35 +0200
Processing by TasksController#index as JSON
  Task Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/index.json.jbuilder (1.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 3.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/tasks?format=json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:15:35 +0200
Processing by TasksController#index as JSON
  Task Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/index.json.jbuilder (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 3.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/tasks?format=json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:15:35 +0200
Processing by TasksController#index as JSON
  Task Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/index.json.jbuilder (2.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 3.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)


Started GET "/tasks?format=json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:15:35 +0200
Processing by TasksController#index as JSON
  Task Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/index.json.jbuilder (0.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 2.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/tasks?format=json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:15:35 +0200
Processing by TasksController#index as JSON
  Task Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/index.json.jbuilder (0.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 4.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/tasks?format=json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:15:35 +0200
Processing by TasksController#index as JSON
  Task Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/index.json.jbuilder (0.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 2.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/tasks?format=json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:15:35 +0200
Processing by TasksController#index as JSON
  Task Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/index.json.jbuilder (3.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 5.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)


Started GET "/tasks?format=json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:15:35 +0200
Processing by TasksController#index as JSON
  Task Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/index.json.jbuilder (0.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 2.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/tasks?format=json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:15:35 +0200
Processing by TasksController#index as JSON
  Task Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/index.json.jbuilder (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 2.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/tasks?format=json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:15:35 +0200
Processing by TasksController#index as JSON
  Task Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/index.json.jbuilder (1.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 4.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)


Started GET "/tasks?format=json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:15:35 +0200
Processing by TasksController#index as JSON
  Task Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/index.json.jbuilder (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 2.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/tasks?format=json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:15:35 +0200
Processing by TasksController#index as JSON
  Task Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/index.json.jbuilder (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 4.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)


Started GET "/tasks?format=json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:15:35 +0200
Processing by TasksController#index as JSON
  Task Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/index.json.jbuilder (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 2.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/tasks?format=json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:15:35 +0200
Processing by TasksController#index as JSON
  Task Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/index.json.jbuilder (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 2.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/tasks?format=json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:15:35 +0200
Processing by TasksController#index as JSON
  Task Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/index.json.jbuilder (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 2.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)


Started GET "/tasks?format=json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:15:35 +0200
Processing by TasksController#index as JSON
  Task Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/index.json.jbuilder (0.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 2.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/tasks?format=json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:15:35 +0200
Processing by TasksController#index as JSON
  Task Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/index.json.jbuilder (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 2.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/tasks?format=json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:15:35 +0200
Processing by TasksController#index as JSON
  Task Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/index.json.jbuilder (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 2.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/tasks?format=json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:15:35 +0200
Processing by TasksController#index as JSON
  Task Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/index.json.jbuilder (1.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 4.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)


Started GET "/tasks?format=json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:15:36 +0200
Processing by TasksController#index as JSON
  Task Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/index.json.jbuilder (2.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 4.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

If not I have just:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:16:00 +0200
Processing by MainController#index as HTML
  Rendered main/index.html.haml within layouts/application (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 61ms (Views: 60.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bg.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-16 15:16:00 +0200
```

**BUT!** On Heroku that page refreshing works just fine! It refresh the page every time I hit refresh button. It's what actually make that thing weird for me. I also installed Puma server on my Rails app instead of default one (Webrick), started my app with it but that didn't help.

So I'll really appreciate if you could tell me what is wrong with my setup? Let me know if you need to see any code or something. I just have no idea what code will help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I've found the answer. The problem was I had in the Chrome DevTools, AngularJS tab (provided by Batarang extension) checkbox "Enable" checked. So that was messing things up. Apparently one should keep that checkbox unchecked and check it only for actually debugging the app.